# Specify fields in a recursive find with cakephp

Tags: sql, mysql, cakephp, find

Suppose I have a table Recipe that hasmany ingredients.

I do a recursive find to grab recipes with their associated ingredients:

```
$this->Recipe->find('all', array('fields' => array('id','title','description')));
```

Here I can use the 'fields' attribute to specify that I only want it to return id, title, and description. However, despite this, cakephp still returns ALL columns from the ingredients table.

How do I tell cakephp that I only want ingredient table's id and name fields?

btw ingredient model is "Ingredient" and the table is ingredients, and the aggregation table is recipes_ingredients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the ContainableBehavior.
http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html

Comment: link comes up blank for me.  Can you fix or post the solution here instead of a link?

Comment: Fixed the link. It applies to Cake 1.x though, I don't know if it's still applicable to 2.x.